# rows gets multiplied because of group by

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion, group-by

I am querying several tables to get the count of each answer of a question.  here what i am doing is for taking out survey we may ask questions with some answer options upon completion of survey we need get the statistics of a survey then we need to count the count of each answer of the question.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT s.NAME AS surveyname,
    COUNT(r.answer_id) AS totalAnswer,
    q.id AS questionid,
    q.question AS question,
    a.answer AS answer,
    COUNT(r.textbox) AS totalTextbox,
    COUNT(r.textboxmulti) AS totalTextboxmulti,
    qt.template AS template,
    s.NAME AS surveyname,
    COUNT(r.other) AS other
FROM surveys s
INNER JOIN survey_results AS sr
    ON s.id = sr.survey_id
INNER JOIN results AS r
    ON sr.id = r.surveyresults_id
INNER JOIN questions AS q
    ON r.question_id = q.id
INNER JOIN questiontypes AS qt
    ON q.questiontype_id = qt.id
LEFT JOIN answers AS a
    ON r.answer_id = a.id
WHERE s.id = < cfqueryparam cfsqltype = "cf_sql_integer" value = "#arguments.surveyid#" >
GROUP BY q.id,
    a.id
ORDER BY a.rank
```

this query working fine exactly what i want. But the problem is while displaying the result on the views what it does is questions gets multiplied with number of answers though I am using cfoutout attribute group with column name questionid. can anyone help me out how can i prevents the multiplication of questions with the number of answers ?

this is the way I am displaying the survey result

```
<cfoutput query="rc.data.questions" group="questionid">
   <cfswitch expression="#rc.data.questions.template#">
      <cfcase value="multiplechoice">
         <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th width="50%">#rc.data.questions.question#</th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>
                     <div class="center">Response Count</div>
                  </th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <cfoutput>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="60%">#rc.data.questions.answer#</td>
                     <td>
                        <div class="center">#rc.data.questions.totalanswer#</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
            </cfoutput>
            <cfif structKeyExists(rc.data.questions, "totalother") AND rc.data.questions.template EQ 'multiplechoiceother' OR rc.data.questions.template EQ 'multiplechoicemultiother'> 
            <tr>
            <td><a href="#buildurl(action='survey.text_other',querystring='id=#questionid#')#" target="_blank">View other Text answers</a></td>
            <td><div class="center">#rc.data.questions.totalother#</div></td>
            </tr>
            </cfif>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         </table>
      </cfcase>
   </cfswitch>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: when using the group attribute on cfoutput, your query should also be ordered on that column.  It doesn't matter if it's a secondary part of your ORDER BY, it just needs to be there, otherwise you can get some weirdness in the output results.  So I'd do `ORDER BY a.rank, questionid` (or you may have to reference it as q.id)

Comment: I did that ORDER BY a.rank and q.id still same problem. I observed that problem due to 'GROUP BY a.id', and also I need to 'GROUP BY a.id' so that I could have the count of each answer of the question.

Comment: Actually, it does matter if the field you want to group on is a secondary part of your order by clause.  If you want to use a column in the group attribute, it has to be the first column in your order by clause.

Comment: @DanBracuk that's the great catch. it works Thanks a lot for pointing out.

Comment: @DanBracuk - You should write that up as an answer.

Comment: @Leigh - If i want to display questions, its answers and its questiontypes in case the result is null (the count(r.answer_id) and count(r.textbox and r.textboxmulti) is null. So what i need to modify in this query?

Comment: @waseem - You mean how do you get all questions to show up in the query resultset even when there's no matching record for `r.answer_id`? I *think* you would need to change some of your `inner` joins to outer joins.  But you should open a new question for that, so others having the same issue will be able to find the answer.

Comment: @Leigh - I have open new question. here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716059/how-do-i-get-show-up-records-when-query-resultset-is-zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the fields in the order by clause has to match the order in which you want to use the group attribute of cfoutput.  If you want to do this:

```
<cfoutput query="SomeQuery" group="field1">
    #data for this grouping#
    <cfoutput group="field2">
        #data for this grouping#
        <cfoutput>
            #ungrouped data#
        </cfoutput>
    </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

then your query has to end with:

```
order by field1, field2, other_fields_if_appropriate
```

Comment: Note, as Dan mentioned in the comments above, it is not enough to just add the "grouped" columns *somewhere* in the `order by` clause. The query must be sorted by the grouped columns **first - and in the same order as your cfoutput "group"** ie By `field1` then `field2`. Otherwise, the "group" will not function as expected.