# how do i get show up records when query resultset is zero?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am querying several tables to get the count of each answer and this query works fine when there is records found in results table. I would like to handle this query in a way that in case if there is no record found in results table for any answer or question it must display count '0' for that value with their respective questions and answers. what i have to make change in this query ? or is there any way so please let me know ? Thanks in advance.

here is my query.

```
SELECT s.NAME AS surveyname,
    COUNT(r.answer_id) AS totalAnswer,
    q.id AS questionid,
    q.question AS question,
    a.answer AS answer,
    COUNT(r.textbox) AS totalTextbox,
    COUNT(r.textboxmulti) AS totalTextboxmulti,
    qt.template AS template,
    s.NAME AS surveyname,
    COUNT(r.other) AS other
FROM surveys s
INNER JOIN survey_results AS sr
    ON s.id = sr.survey_id
INNER JOIN results AS r
    ON sr.id = r.surveyresults_id
INNER JOIN questions AS q
    ON r.question_id = q.id
INNER JOIN questiontypes AS qt
    ON q.questiontype_id = qt.id
LEFT JOIN answers AS a
    ON r.answer_id = a.id
WHERE s.id = < cfqueryparam cfsqltype = "cf_sql_integer" value = "#arguments.surveyid#" >
GROUP BY q.id,
    a.id
ORDER BY q.id, a.id a.rank
```

In case if there is no matching record found it should display something like below.

```
surveyname totalanswer qid question answer totaltextbox totaltextboxmulti template totalother
somename     0         1 what ?   yes     0              0              multiple  0
somename     0         1 what ?   no      0              0              multiple  0
```

if there is matching record then it should display the count in totalanswer or totaltextbox etc,.

Comment: if there is possibility of 0 records in results table for any question or answer, then you should `LEFT JOIN` the results table.

Comment: @SlowCoder thats right, i didnt consider that....

Comment: @Slowcoder - when i did left to the results table it is not showing the count of r.textbox, r.textboxmulti and r.other as these columns are to be count base questionid.

Comment: @waseem - I am not sure I fully understand the problem... What do you mean by "not showing the count"? What are you expecting to happen if there is no matching record? Can you post a data dump that better illustrates the issue?

Comment: @Leigh -  here what i want is if there is no matching record found it must show surveyname, question, and its answers with their respective results count columns should display with count zero.

Comment: @waseem - It still sounds like an `outer/left` join should fix the problem. (Though see the important caveat about the `where` clause below). However, since we cannot see the results, I do not know what the current version is doing wrong/differently. Are the records not showing up at all, have the wrong counts, ...? Can you show us a sample?

Comment: @Waseem - i think we will need to understand more about your table relationships.  Looking at your query, my only guess is that you may have to `LEFT JOIN` all of these tables with the survey table.

Comment: Can a record in results be both TexttBox and textboxmulti???

Comment: @Leigh - I have updated my question, i try to make it clear.

Comment: But what do the *actual* query results look like? Also, I agree with @SlowCoder. We need to understand the table relationships, because if you are using all `left` joins, as he suggested, you should be getting something *similar* to that result already.

Comment: @Leigh - when i did left joins it works but not exactly. suppose if a question has two answer options like Yes and No and any user select Yes then count(r.answer_id) for Yes should be 1 and count(r.answer_id) for No should be 0.  my problem is its not even showing the records with 0 count.

Comment: @waseem - Well again, missing records points *usually* means to not the wrong kind of join. But without more specific information, we can only throw out guesses. As SlowCoder said, we need to know more about the relationships and actual data. Use something like http://sqlfiddle.com to throw up a sample we can test independently.

Comment: @Leigh - here I have dumped all tables schema with some sample data https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7267344.

Comment: here sqlfiddle for my tables http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a73c7/1

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this `COUNT(ifnull(r.other,0)) AS other`

```
    SELECT s.NAME AS surveyname,
    COUNT(r.answer_id) AS totalAnswer,
    q.id AS questionid,
    q.question AS question,
    a.answer AS answer,
    COUNT(r.textbox) AS totalTextbox,
    COUNT(r.textboxmulti) AS totalTextboxmulti,
    qt.template AS template,
    s.NAME AS surveyname,
    COUNT(ifnull(r.other,0)) AS other
FROM surveys s
INNER JOIN survey_results AS sr
    ON s.id = sr.survey_id
INNER JOIN results AS r
    ON sr.id = r.surveyresults_id
INNER JOIN questions AS q
    ON r.question_id = q.id
INNER JOIN questiontypes AS qt
    ON q.questiontype_id = qt.id
LEFT JOIN answers AS a
    ON r.answer_id = a.id
WHERE s.id = < cfqueryparam cfsqltype = "cf_sql_integer" value = "#arguments.surveyid#" >
GROUP BY q.id,
    a.id
ORDER BY a.rank
```

EDIT

Also as @SlowCoder suggested, try using `LEFT JOIN` on results table.

Comment: Also, do not reference any of the outer joined tables in the `where` clause. Otherwise, you cancel out the `outer` join ie you are still doing an `inner` join.

Comment: I did but it is not showing up the count textbox, textboxmulti and other columns count.